# Как сгенерировать временный xls файл в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php7.3

Есть данные, которые отбираются через фильтр. Эти данные записываются в xls файл путем PHPExcel. Этот файл можно скачать в течение определенного времени. Как сделать в Laravel чтобы этот файл удалялся через какое-то время? Есть ли какие-то функции или нужно в планировщике у Laravel настраивать проверку на время?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#signed-urls

Comment: @doox911 Про ссылку временную - я в курсе. Но удалиться ли файл потом? Мне важно, что бы созданный файл при запросе удалялся с ссылкой на него потом.

Comment: Варианта так-то два: либо вручную отдавать файл, после чего его удалять, либо, к примеру, создать диск temp, куда записывать файлы и планировщиком удалять (желательно с проверкой нет ли с файлом операций в данный момент, аля делать проверку last modified)

Comment: Используйте системный планировщик, установленный на нужный вам период (каждую минуту, к примеру), и пусть он запускает скрипт который будет удалять файлы, у которых истек срок хранения. Храните срок либо как константу, либо в БД для каждого файла на ваше усмотрение. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965778/the-correct-way-to-delete-all-files-older-than-2-days-in-php) с анлгоязычного SO. Если хотите использовать именно Laravel, то читайте о его [методах](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling).

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Да, я так и начал делать. А что если время создания файла добавлять к названию файла? Это хуже будет чем в БД хранить?

Comment: А вам обязательно записывать в файл? Можно генерировать содержимое на лету и отдавать пользователю. Минуя сохранение на диск

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлюснин можно и так, но это не нужно так как у файлов уже есть дата создания, которую можно получить через [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filemtime.php) (усли файл в дальнейшем не изменяется)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov вот этого не знал. Спасибо. 
Я в итоге сделал удаление через планировщик. Он просто дату создания проверяет и удаляет, если она выходит за пределы нужного времени.

Comment: @ArchDemon да, человек выкачивает файл с определенными заказами и дальше работает офлайн с ними.

Comment: Что да? Если человек выкачивает файл и дальше с ним работает, то нет ни какого смыла сохранять этот файл на сервере. Генерируйте содержимое файла на лету, минуя стадию сохранения на диск.

Comment: @ArchDemon Хорошо. Как это можно сделать?